# Need a bigger mouse cursor

Tags: directx, autohotkey

Windows 7 appears to only support 48x48 pixel mouse cursors natively.  My dad is half blind, so this isn't good enough.

Looking around a little, I see that there is [High DPI Cursor Changer Beta](https://sourceforge.net/p/cursorchanger/home/Home/) on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/cursorchanger/home/Home/).  Unfortunately, it states that it is limited to Windows 8 and above.  Even if he did have Windows 8, I still don't think it would be big enough.

I've been thinking about some other alternatives which might get the job done.  One is to use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) to track the mouse position and type, and using that information, put up a larger bitmap under the cursor that is displayed on a click through window.

This seems doable, but I would like it if I could invert the information beneath the cursor as the inverted mouse cursor does.  I'm thinking that this would require using the DirectX API, which I'm totally unfamiliar with.  As I don't have a whole lot of time to devote to this, it would be great if someone could point out some key concepts and API calls so that I can move through this project as fast as possible.

I've also looked into zooming in, but seems using that is also problematic as it requires that he get it in and out of that state and zoom in and out fairly easily, which he can't as he can't really touch type and his fingertips don't have very much sensation, making it hard to navigate the keyboard effectively.

If there are any other ideas, I'd be interested in hearing about them as well.

Comment: 1) change the screen resolution, 2) use a larger monitor, 3) Use a computer display instead of a monitor, 4) use a television with an HDMI/DisplayPort/VGA input

Comment: @JimU 1) no, would require that some of the windows won't fit. 2) no, don't have the space. 3) see 2.

Comment: Control Panel > Small Icons > Mouse Properties > Visibility > **Display Pointer Trails** and **Show location of pointer when I press the CTRL key**

Comment: @JimU, thanks, but I've already have told that to my father.  Even when he knows roughly where it is, it would still help him to have a bigger mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried Bill Myers solution, so I think that the cursors are still the max. size, but check out Bill's link: https://www.bmyers.com/public/high_visibility_cursors.cfm

Comment: Thanks Robert, I've already have been there.  It is basically going to make 48x48 cursor that is red.  It is still not big enough.

Comment: I should have checked but I didn't want to install something I don't need and the page doesn't mention the size. I sure hope you get a solution for your dad.